# How to get the python3 path in ubuntu without which command

Tags: linux

**Problem:**
I want to get the python3 path in my Ubuntu VM. Like /usr/xyz/python3

**More Information:**
I dont see the 'which' command present in my envt.
I tried to 'sudo apt install which', but it fails saying that no such package found.

Answer (score 1):

#### Get path of the executable python binary

##### Python code

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

##### Command

```sh
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

Comment: This dumps a list of python paths, but it is not the correct one that can be used as the shabang line executable.
I manually found that the executable is /usr/bin/python3

Comment: I updated the answer, it should fix your issue now. Please mark it as an acceptable answer if it does so. @AlanSaldanha

Answer (score 1):

The `where` and `which` commands are often an alias to the inbuilt bash command `type`.
I have it also as app in `busybox` on most embedded devices.
Also tablets and smartfons with the app: ConnectBot
If present on your machine too; then: `type -p python3`

But anyway, the correct/recommended way to make a SHEBANG is not to use type, where or which.
If your PATH environment variable targets the usually folders for installed executables just use: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Example: test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
print('No error - But i return 1 and not 0')
sys.exit(1)
```

Making than executable with: `chmod +x test.py`
And execute it...

```sh
$ ./test.py
No error - But i return 1 and not 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt install which` is failing because `which` is part of `debianutils`; most executables don't come as their own package.

`sudo apt install debianutils`

Answer (score 1):

If you use bash, you can just do :

```
type -p python
```